# WPF - BindingExpression path error

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a observable collection in my view model like in the following.

```
           private ObservableCollection<MyClass> _myData;
           public  ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyData
           {
                  set { _myData=value; }
                  get { return _myData }
           }
```

The structure of MyClas is like in the following.

```
          class MyClass 
          {
                 private string name;
                 public string Name;
                 {
                     set { name=value;}
                     get { return name;}
                 }
           }
```

I have binded the above observable collection to a combobox in my view like this.

```
       <ComboBox  Width="200" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.MyData.Name,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
```

Still it says

> BindingExpression path error: 'Name' property not found on 'object'
>   ''ObservableCollection`1' (HashCode=22227061)'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.MyData.Name; DataItem='MyView'
>   (Name=''); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is
>   'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

I find this strange. why does it say that Name property is not there in observable collection ?

Comment: Change the property `Name` to something else, like `DName` and try...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get that error message because the property path `DataContext.MyData.Name` resolves a `Name` property in `MyData`, which isn't there and doesn't make sense.

You should bind the `ItemsSource` property to the item collection, and set the `DisplayMemberPath` to the `Name` property of the item class:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.MyData,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                        AncestorType=UserControl}}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

Alternatively you could create a DataTemplate that binds to the `Name` property:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.MyData,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                        AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```